# Supply information automatically to simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, form-for

I'm working on a simple little Rails social network and right now I am trying to automatically fill in the name of the currently signed in user when creating a new status update. My original code let them select their user name from a drop down which is silly - when you go on Facebook, you fill out the box and it automatically knows that it belongs to you. Here is my original code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@status, html: {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <% if @status.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@status.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this status from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @status.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all, label_method: :full_name %>
  <%= f.input :content %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is what I am trying to replace it with:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@status, html: {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <% if @status.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@status.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this status from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @status.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :user_id, current_user.full_name %>
  <%= f.input :content %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It doesn't like this and says "can't convert Symbol into Integer"
How can I supply it with the logged in user's full name without ever giving them the option to chose another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_id` is the forreign key to `User`, it holds something like `current_user.id` not it's name.

It seems, that the user is already signed in, so you just need to show the name and provide the id to the `create` action:

```
<%= f.input :user_id, as: :hidden %>
<%= current_user.name %> <%# just for information %>
```

and set it in the new `@status` in the controller:

```
def new
  @status = Status.new(user: current_user)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first input of the form is specified as an input for the `:user_id` which is an integer in your table of users.  Putting a full name there is creating a mismatch in data types.  Does this help?

Now that you want the username to be displayed without the user being able to change what is displayed, is there really a need to have this as an input?  Can you just display the username in a normal `<div></div>`, so to speak?